# Why do the dimensions not line up when I calculate this (directional) derivative using the chain rule?

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

an arbitrary, differentiable function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and the function $\gamma: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ defined as $\gamma(t) = u + tv$, where $u, v$ are fixed vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, I'm trying to find the derivative with respect to $t$ of $(f \circ \gamma)(t)$ at $t = 0$.

From the chain rule, I know that $D(f \circ \gamma)(t) = Df(\gamma(t)) \cdot D \gamma(t)$. I'm confused, though, because I thought that $D(f \circ \gamma)(t)$ (the left-hand side) would give me a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, but $Df(\gamma(t))$ gives me a function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and $D \gamma(t) = v$, which is a constant function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, so the right-hand side gives me a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

It's a simple directional derivative that I've done a million times, and I'm probably missing something easy because it's late, but why don't these dimensions line up? What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right-hand side gives you the product of a $1\times n$-Matrix with a $n\times 1$-Matrix, which is a $1\times 1$-Matrix. You might aswell identify this matrix with its entry.

A bit more specific:

$Df(\gamma(t)) = (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(\gamma(t)),\dots, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}(\gamma(t)))$

$D\gamma(t) = (\gamma_1'(t),...,\gamma_n'(t))^T$

Comment: Since $\gamma'(t) = v$, the second matrix in your answer is just $(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$, right?

Comment: Yes, thats right, but it is $(v_1,...,v_n)^T$.

Comment: Oh, right, because it's a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, so it's represented by an $n \times 1$ matrix. Thanks!